# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression on ternary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, conditional-operator

Currently getting 
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

I tried returning an empty div at the end of my ternary operator but still get the same error.

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (response && !isLoading) {
            showNotification({
                variant: "success",
                message: `Your invitation ${
                    name.props ? name.props.children : name
                }-${data} was successfully sent.`
            });
            closeAlert();
            viewName === "GetAllData"
                ? dispatch({
                      type: "FETCH_DATA",
                      payload: { loading: true }
                  })
                : dispatch({
                      type: "FETCH_AVAILABLE_STAFF",
                      payload: { loading: true }
                  });
        }
        return <div />;
    }, [response, isLoading]);
```

Comment: Why would you return a div? It wont be rendered anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is complaining about how you use a ternary instead of using an if/else statement to do the work. The code is expecting

```
if (viewName === "GetAllData") {
  dispatch({
    type: "FETCH_DATA",
    payload: { loading: true }
  })
} else {
  dispatch({
    type: "FETCH_AVAILABLE_STAFF",
    payload: { loading: true }
  });
}
```

If you want to use a ternary you need to do it with the objects, since only thing that is different is the type, use it on the type.

```
dispatch({
  type: viewName === "GetAllData" ? "FETCH_DATA" : "FETCH_AVAILABLE_STAFF",
  payload: { loading: true }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with returning the `div` ( why even return a `div` ?) but rather,

```
viewName === 'GetAllData'
  ? dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_DATA',
      payload: { loading: true },
    })
  : dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_AVAILABLE_STAFF',
      payload: { loading: true },
    });
```

The ternary operation above is an `expression`. Change that to an `if` block.

You need not return anything from `useEffect` in this use case. Also `useEffect` will not render anything as it is a hook in place to perform side effects.